# How to get the largest number of trips performed

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Find the license numbers (LicenseCardNo) of all drivers who performed the largest number of trips. I am not able to write the SQL select statement to achieve this. Would appreciate if you guys can help.  Below is the sample data regarding my tables and the values inside the table? I have also attached the code which I have done so far also.

```
 DRIVER(OwnerNo, LicenseCardNo,STATUS,)
 PRIMARY KEY(OwnerNo)
 UNIQUE(LicenseCardNo)
 FOREIGN KEY(OwnerNo) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(OwnerNo)
 CHECK ( STATUS IN ('MAIN DRIVER', 'DRIVER', 'TAXI DRIVER')) )

 ( A29, DR1, 'MAIN DRIVER' )
 ( A28, DR2, 'MAIN DRIVER' )
 ( A25, DR3, 'TAXI DRIVER' )
 ( A25, DR22, 'DRIVER' )
 ( A20, DR6, 'DRIVER' )
 ( A23, DR7, 'TAXI DRIVER' )
 ( A30, DR8, 'TAXI DRIVER' )

TRIP( TripNo,LicenseCardNo,CarReg,TRIP_DATE,)
PRIMARY KEY (TripNo),
FOREIGN KEY (LicenseCardNo) REFERENCES DRIVER(LicenseCardNo),
FOREIGN KEY (CarReg) REFERENCES TRUCK(CarReg)

( 1, DR1, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 )
( 2, DR2, 'GBC222', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 )
( 3, DR1, 'GBC270', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-133 )
( 4, DR3, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 )
( 5, DR22, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 )
( 6, DR22, 'GBC222', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-124 )
( 7, DR7, 'KKK007', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 )
( 8, DR1, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 )
( 9, DR2, 'QRT834', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 )
(10, DR22, 'GBC270', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-122 )
```

This is how far I can go about. Not sure how to proceed on. I managed to achieve this with some help from the internet. Please advise.

```
SELECT DRIVER.LicenseCardNo AS LICENSE_NO, COUNT(TRIP.TripNo) AS TOTAL_NO_TRIPS
FROM DRIVER LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP ON DRIVER.LicenseCardNo = TRIP.LicenseCardNo
GROUP BY DRIVER.LicenseCardNo
ORDER BY DRIVER.LicenseCardNo;
```

This code lists the no of trips travelled by each driver.

So now I need to find the license numbers (LicenseCardNo) of all drivers who performed the largest number of trips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much on your way there.  Here is one way, using the analytic functions in Oracle:

```
with q as (
    SELECT DRIVER.LicenseCardNo AS LICENSE_NO, COUNT(TRIP.TripNo) AS TOTAL_NO_TRIPS
    FROM DRIVER LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP ON DRIVER.LicenseCardNo = TRIP.LicenseCardNo
    GROUP BY DRIVER.LicenseCardNo
)
select licenseCardNo
from (select q.*, rank() over (order by Total_No_Trips order by 1 desc) as ranking
      from q
     ) q1
where ranking = 1
ORDER BY LicenseCardNo;
```

Actually, I also realize that your original query is needlessly complicated.  You don't need the join back to DRIVER, since you have the license number.  You can express this as:

```
select licenseCardNo
from (select q.*, rank() over (order by Total_No_Trips order by 1 desc) as ranking
      from (select LicenseCardNo, count(*) as Total_No_Trips
            from trips t
            group by LicenseCardNo
           ) q
     ) q1
where ranking = 1
ORDER BY LicenseCardNo;
```

Also, if you just want to see the maximum number first in the output, then you can do:

```
order by 2 desc
```

In your original query.  This will order by the count rather than the license card number.

Another (and usually less efficien)t way to do this is with the group by/join approach:

```
with q as (
    select LicenseCardNo, count(*) as Total_No_Trips
    from trips t
    group by LicenseCardNo
)
select q.*
from q
where Total_No_Trips = (select max(Total_No_Trips) from q)
```

Comment: I want make to codes easy so that the person who is going to take over can understand. Not sure if he is good in oracle.

Comment: You can do the same thing using a group by and join.  However, the ranking functions *are* part of the SQL standard now; they have been part of Oracle for over a decade; and, they are generally more efficient than the group by/join approach.

Comment: what does q and q1 referes. Can i use only q only?

Comment: Thanks. I understand now much better. I am able to relate to your simple version to the oracle version thanks alot.

Comment: @user1571494 . . These are aliases on tables/subqueries.  Yes, you can give all of them the same name, since they are not combined together.

Comment: When i run your 1st and 2nd  statements it giving me missing right parenthesis. But i cant figure out any error. Your codes are correct to me. And u assist to check. Please